# How to make flex item have same width on each row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I make each `flex` items have the same width? Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
.video-container {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.video {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video" style="background: red;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: blue;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: yellow;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: green;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: orange;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: red;"></video>
</div>
```

**Result**:
[image: click here]

This means that the maximum item for a row would be 4 items, then it'll go down to a new row.

This works well if we have 4/8 items but if I have only 6 items, then the last 2 will grow bigger than the rest.

How to make them all have the same width?

**UPDATED**

My bad, I forgot to give the full explanation. The issue on top can be fixed by just doing flex: 0 0 25%; but I also want the item to take up the spaces. So if it's just:

1 item, then it'll grow full screen,
2 item, then it'll be half,
and up until 4 items.

Basically the layout they do in google meet.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the `flex-grow` property of the child elements to `0` instead of `1`

```css
.video-container {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.video {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video" style="background: red;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: blue;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: yellow;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: green;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: orange;"></video>
  <video class="video" style="background: red;"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, this fixes part of the problem but not what i was looking for. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @stalwart1014, I couldn't really get your question, if you could post a picture of what exactly you want, it would be useful for the viewers to come up with a solution